# AWK: Pattern match multiline data with variable line number

Tags: regex, linux, awk, multiline

I am trying to write a script which will analyze data from a pipe. The problem is, a single element is described in a variable number of lines. Look at the example data set:

```
3 14 -30.48 17.23
4  1 -18.01 12.69
4  3 -11.01  2.69
8 12 -21.14 -8.76
8 14 -18.01 -5.69
8 12 -35.14 -1.76
9  2  -1.01 22.69
10 1 -88.88 17.28
10 1   -.88 14.28
10 1   5.88  1.28
10 1  -8.88 -7.28
```

In this case, the first entry is what defines the event to which the following data belongs. In the case of event number 8, we have data in 3 lines. To simplify the rather complex problem that I am trying to solve, let us imagine, that I want to calculate the following expression:

```
sum_i($2 * ($3 + $4))
```

Where i is taken over all lines belonging to a given element. The output I want to produce would then look like:

```
3=-185.5   [14(-30.48+17.23) ]
4=-30.28   [1(-18.01+12.69) + 3(-11.01+2.69)]
8=-1106.4  [...]
```

I thus need a script which reads all the lines that have the same index entry.

I am an AWK newbie and I've started learning the language a couple of days ago. I am now uncertain whether I will be able to achieve what I want. Therefore:

1. Is this doable with AWK?
2. If not, whith what? SED?
3. If yes, how? I would be grateful if one provided a link describing how this can be implemented.

Finally, I know that there is a similar question: [Can awk patterns match multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350856/can-awk-patterns-match-multiple-lines), however, I do not have a constant pattern which separates my data.

Thanks!

Comment: It is perfectly doable in awk and do not even try to do it in sed : ) What is the desired output?

Comment: For example the sum I have quoted and the index number (the first column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
awk '{ar[$1]+=$2*($3+$4)}
      END{for (key in ar) 
              {print key"="ar[key]}}' inputFile
```

For each line input we do the desired calculation and sum the result in an array. `$1` serves as the key of the array.
When the entire file is read, we print the results in the `END{...}`-block.

The output for the given sample input is:

```
4=-30.28
8=-1133.4
9=43.36
10=-67.2
3=-185.5
```

If sorting of the output is required, you might want to have a look at gawk's `asorti` function or Linux' `sort`-command (e.g. `awk '{...} inputFile' | sort -n`).

This solution does not require that the input is sorted.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'id!=$1{if(id){print id"="sum;sum=0};id=$1}{sum+=$2*($3+$4)} END{print id"="sum}' file
3=-185.5
4=-30.28
8=-1133.4
9=43.36
10=-67.2
```

Comment: You sure "id" can never be zero? What other numbers is `id` guaranteed not to be? Test `if (id!="")` or even clearer `if (NR>1)`, not `if(id)`, and move `id=$1` out of the action block that's only executed when `id!=$1` and into the `sum+=...` block.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton.  `awk 'id!=$1&&NR>1{print id"="sum;sum=0}{id=$1;sum+=$2*($3+$4)} END{print id"="sum}'`

Answer (score 1):

yet another similar awk

```
$ awk -v OFS="=" 'NR==1{p=$1}
                  p!=$1{print p,s; s=0; p=$1}
                       {s+=$2*($3+$4)}
                    END{print p,s}' file

3=-185.5
4=-30.28
8=-1133.4
9=43.36
10=-67.2
```

ps. Your calculation for "8" seems off.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for noticing. It seems manual calcuation skills are fading away.