# How to get location of the code snippets in C++?

Tags: python, c++, .net

I have cpp codes of version A and version B, In version B, I have code snippets under these comment tags like

```
//B specific - START
..something here..
//B specific - END
```

I want to extract B specific code snippets and place them at appropriate location in Version A. For this, I want to extract location of the B Specific Code Snippets. Is there any algorithm ?

For Example 
**VersionA.cpp**

```
// Program to print all combination of size r in an array of size n
#include <stdio.h>
void combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[], int start, int end, 
                    int index, int r);

// The main function that prints all combinations of size r
// in arr[] of size n. This function mainly uses combinationUtil()
void printCombination(int arr[], int n, int r)
{
    // A temporary array to store all combination one by one
    int data[r];
    int data[m];
    // Print all combination using temprary array 'data[]'
    combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n-1, 0, r);
}

/* arr[] ---> Input Array
data[] ---> Temporary array to store current combination
start & end ---> Staring and Ending indexes in arr[]
index ---> Current index in data[]
r ---> Size of a combination to be printed */
void combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[], int start, int end,
                    int index, int r)
{
    // Current combination is ready to be printed, print it
    if (index == r)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<r; j++)
            printf("%d ", data[j]);
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }

    // replace index with all possible elements. The condition
    // "end-i+1 >= r-index" makes sure that including one element
    // at index will make a combination with remaining elements
    // at remaining positions
    for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++)
    {
        int temp;
        data[index] = arr[i];
        combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r);
    }
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int r = 3;
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    printCombination(arr, n, r);
}
```

**VersionB.cpp**

```
// Program to print all combination of size r in an array of size n
#include <stdio.h>
//B specific - START
#include "...."
#include "...."
//B specific - END

void combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[], int start, int end, 
                     int index, int r);

// The main function that prints all combinations of size r
// in arr[] of size n. This function mainly uses combinationUtil()
void printCombination(int arr[], int n, int r)
{
    // A temporary array to store all combination one by one
    int data[r];
    //B specific - START
    ..something here..
    //B specific - END

    // Print all combination using temprary array 'data[]'
    combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n-1, 0, r);
}

/* arr[]  ---> Input Array
   data[] ---> Temporary array to store current combination
   start & end ---> Staring and Ending indexes in arr[]
   index  ---> Current index in data[]
   r ---> Size of a combination to be printed */
void combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[], int start, int end,
                     int index, int r)
{
    // Current combination is ready to be printed, print it
    if (index == r)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<r; j++)
            printf("%d ", data[j]);
            //B specific - START
            ..something here..
            //B specific - END
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }

    // replace index with all possible elements. The condition
    // "end-i+1 >= r-index" makes sure that including one element
    // at index will make a combination with remaining elements
    // at remaining positions
    for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++)
    {
        //B specific - START
        ..something here..
        //B specific - END
        data[index] = arr[i];
        combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r);
    }
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int r = 3;
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    printCombination(arr, n, r);
}
```

**Output VersionA.cpp** should be like this,

```
// Program to print all combination of size r in an array of size n
#include <stdio.h>
void combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[], int start, int end, 
                    int index, int r);

// The main function that prints all combinations of size r
// in arr[] of size n. This function mainly uses combinationUtil()
void printCombination(int arr[], int n, int r)
{
    // A temporary array to store all combination one by one
    int data[r];
    //B specific - START
    ..something here..
    //B specific - END
    int data[m];
    // Print all combination using temprary array 'data[]'
    combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n-1, 0, r);
}

/* arr[] ---> Input Array
data[] ---> Temporary array to store current combination
start & end ---> Staring and Ending indexes in arr[]
index ---> Current index in data[]
r ---> Size of a combination to be printed */
void combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[], int start, int end,
                    int index, int r)
{
    // Current combination is ready to be printed, print it
    if (index == r)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<r; j++)
            printf("%d ", data[j]);
            //B specific - START
            ..something here..
            //B specific - END
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }

    // replace index with all possible elements. The condition
    // "end-i+1 >= r-index" makes sure that including one element
    // at index will make a combination with remaining elements
    // at remaining positions
    for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++)
    {
        int temp;
        //B specific - START
        ..something here..
        //B specific - END
        data[index] = arr[i];
        combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r);
    }
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int r = 3;
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    printCombination(arr, n, r);
}
```

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350856/can-awk-patterns-match-multiple-lines#14350923

Comment: You can `grep` those snippets.

Comment: I can extract the snippets, but i don't know how to get the location of the snippets

Comment: doesnt extracting them require to know the location? Imho your question is not quite clear. Your are looking for a text editor function and the language tags are actually irrelevant?

Comment: [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) or [std::search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) may be useful here.

Comment: I thought python or .net might be useful to extract the lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Araxis Merge tool, Get File Comparison Report. Analyse the report file using Python script. And Carry out the required Merge Action