# A question about AWK multiple line recognition

Tags: awk

I've just read [Can awk patterns match multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14350856/3184351), whose accepted solution is a script that print the line after `first half`.

```
how
second half #1
now
first half
second half #2
brown
second half #3
cow
```

```
/second half/ {
  if(lastLine == "first half") {
    print
  }
}

{ lastLine = $0 }
```

This gives `second half #2`.

I *can't* understand why `{ lastLine = $0 }` has to go *after* `/second half/ {...}/`.  I tried interchanging them, and I got *nothing*.

```
{ lastLine = $0 }

/second half/ {
  if(lastLine == "first half") {
    print
  }
}
```

I tried reading `man awk`, but it *doesn't* cover state machines.  Searching "awk state machine" gives only the linked SO question.

Comment: The if statement refers to variable lastLine, so obviously it is matter whether lastLine gets its value before or after the if (Unless I didn't understand your question at all).

Comment: In the 2nd script, `lastLine` gets the value before `if`, but I don't understand why there's nothing printed out.

Comment: In the 2nd script, `lastLine` is set to the current line (i.e `$0`), and the action coming after it is executed only if current line matches `second half`. In the action, `lastLine` variable is checked if it is `first half`, which always results false because `second half ...` =/= `first half`. Thus nothing gets printed.

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks for reponse, but I still don't get why that's different from the 1st script.  In the 1st script, `lastLine` is also set to current line `$0$`.

Comment: Look, in 1st script `lastLine` keeps *last line*, but for 2nd it keeps *current line* instead, okay? because in 1st, it is assigned *after* checking if it is `first half`, in 2nd, it is assigned *before* checking if it is `first half`.

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks again for explanation.  I hope I get you correctly: for the 1st script, at the 1st line `/.../{if(lastLine == "first half"){...}}` is omitted, then `lastLine` gets value `$0`, then repeat for second line, ..., until `/.../{if(...){...}}` is matched, so that `lastLine` gets value from the previous line.  The examples about AWK variables that I've seen only involves one single action, so I've scratched my head on this.  How can I learn more about this?  I've gone through GNU's user manual and I can't find an example like this.

Comment: by trial-error like everybody else

Comment: How to write a state machine is a general programming thing, it's not an awk thing. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine (and a very old paper by a very young man and his peers at https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6772875 if you care :-) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered by @oguzismail's comment.  To clear this question from the unanswered queue, I'm going to expand it into an answer.

AWK processes text *record-wise*.  By default, the record seperator (RS) is the newline character `\n`, so AWK treats each line as a record.

In the first (correct) AWK script, when the first record `how` is processed, the match `/second half/` in

```
/second half/ {
  if(lastLine == "first half") {
    print
  }
}
```

is evaluated to *false* and `{ lastLine = $0 }` saves the current record `$0` (i.e. `how`) to the variable `lastLine`.

Then the second record `second half #1` comes, and it matches `/second half/`, so the block `{if (lastLine == "first half"){...}}` is executed with `lastLine` as the previous record (`how`), even though `$0` is `second half #1`.

As the process goes on, the record `second half #2` will eventually get through the nested block `{}` so that it's printed.

If I invert the two actions in the AWK script, `lastLine` will always save the current record `$0`, while `/second half/` get matched if and only if `$0` contains `second half`, which *doesn't* equal to `first half`.  Therefore, it's *impossible* that `$0` get `print`ed by the 2<sup>nd</sup> AWK script.