# Use awk to check for a blank line prior to a bulleted list in markdown

Tags: awk

Some Markdown processors require a blank line before a bulleted list.

So the list

```
This is a bulleted list: 
- line 1
- line 2
- line 3
```

Will be incorrectly rendered as

```
This is a bulleted list: - line 1 - line 2 - line 3
```

How can I use awk to check that lines starting with "- " are preceded by either a blank line or another line starting with "- "?

(I am using dash-space as the start token to avoid confusion with the document front matter, which uses three dashes as a separator.)

Please note: unlike the first question referenced in the comments, this is a search for an anti-pattern - something *not* occurring in the file.

Using `pcregrep` this is straightforward:

```
pcregrep -Mc '^[A-Z][a-z].*\n- ' $filename
```

but it's not clear to me how to do it using `awk`.

What I'm doing is:

```
awkcommand='
/- / {
  if(lastLine != "") {
    print FILENAME
    exit
  }
}

{ lastLine = $0 }
'
awk "$awkcommand" data
```

which catches a single bullet following a non blank line.  But when I try to add more conditions (if prior line not blank AND prior line does not start with a bullet), it fails - so for example, this:

```
  if(lastLine != "" && lastline !~/^- /) {
```

does not work: it gives a false positive on this file

```
This is a test

- abc
- def
```

Comment: it can be simplified for one-liners, but the accepted answer here explains it well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350856/can-awk-patterns-match-multiple-lines

Comment: This is the opposite of the question people are saying it duplicates it.  We're looking for an anti-pattern, not a pattern.

Comment: you can use logical operators to get the desired result.. I didn't vote to close the question, but the probable reason you are downvoted and not answered is because you haven't added you own efforts to the question

Comment: Your awk works, just tested, including `if(lastLine != "" && lastline !~/^- /) {` Do you get different output than the filename printed?

Comment: See sample data where it gives a false positive.

Comment: Seems it is just a typo. Replace `lastline` with `lastLine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is OK, there was only a typo in your additional `if`, it works.

```
awk '/- / {
  if(lastLine != "" && lastLine !~ /^- /) {
    print FILENAME
    exit
  }
}
{ lastLine = $0 }' file
```

Comment: For anyone who might want to use this, my final check was: `if(lastLine != "" && lastLine !~/^- / && lastLine !~/^[ ]+- / && lastLine !~/^#/ && lastLine != "```") {`

Answer (score 1):

```
gawk '/^-/{ if (bl==pbl) bl=1; else { pbl=bl; bl=0; }}
    { if (bl==1) print ""; 
      print $0 }'  inputfile
```

Given the input file:

```
This is a bulleted list:
- line 1
- line 2
- line 3
```

The output will be:

```
This is a bulleted list:

- line 1
- line 2
- line 3
```

EDIT:

If you just want to print the filename:

```
awk '/^-/{ if (bl==pbl) bl=1; else { pbl=bl; bl=0; }}
    { if (bl==1) print FILENAME; }'    inputfiles*
```

In this case no special things are used that need gawk, so it should work with awk also.

Comment: Great - but I was hoping to use regular awk, and just identify the condition by printing the filename (not fix it).